# How To Change Text Animation using html and css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to make a text box that can be automatically changed every like 10-15 seconds like it does here in this link: `https://www.groupamana.com/`

On the video background there is a text, and every time you scroll it shows you another text. All I want is help me to make it on my html and css that every 5-15 sec it changes text by its own **I want it all done on css and html**

I have tried to make it by my own but none of it worked

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 95px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.content a {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.content a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.background-clip {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
  .background-clip {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
  .background-clip {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="background-clip">
            <source src="../images/videoproject.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

  <div class="content">
    <h1>Explore More</h1>
  </div>

  <h3 class="rat">Welcome to our website</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you describe more what the reference to scroll entails? I don’t understand how that fits with the requirement to change the text every few seconds.

Comment: Thank you. But I've found my answer to  my question i will publish it soon

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.content{
    text-align: center;
}

.content h1{
    font-size: 95px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content a{
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.content a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.background-clip{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
    .background-clip{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
    .background-clip{
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}


.banner-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
width: 100%;
color: red;
}

.banner-text h2{
text-align: center;
font-size: 60px;
margin: 0;
color: darkturquoise;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-bottom: 150px;
}


.box{
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: century gothic;
}

.b1{
    animation: ani1 40s infinite;
}

.b2{
    animation: ani2 40s infinite;
}

.b3{
    animation: ani3 40s infinite;
}

.b4{
    animation: ani4 40s infinite;
}

.b5{
    animation: ani5 40s infinite;
}


@keyframes ani1 {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20%{
        opacity: 0;
    }

}

@keyframes ani2 {
    20%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    30%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    40%{
        opacity: 0;
    }

}

@keyframes ani3 {
    40%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    60%{
        opacity: 0;
    }


}

@keyframes ani4 {
    60%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    70%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    80%{
        opacity: 0;
    }

}

@keyframes ani5 {
    80%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    90%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">

        <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="background-clip">
            <source src="../images/videoproject.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        <div class="content">
            <h1>Explore More</h1>
        </div>

<!--this is the place of the div container-->

        <div class="banner">
            <div class="banner-text">
             <h2>hey</h2>
                <div class="text-wrapper">

                    <div class="box b1">
                        <li>this is our new website</li>
                        <li>this is our new website</li>
                        <li>this is our new website</li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box b2">hello </div>
                    <div class="box b3">Welcome </div>
                    <div class="box b4">This is our website </div>
                    <div class="box b5">Thank you! </div>
        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the answer of the question above and sorry if i wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: I would like only for help if we can remove now the timer and make it on scroll like wehn you scroll down with the mouse the next sentence appears and the first one dissappear

Comment: all i mean is like now in the current code the text appears after the time that i put is done (now i want to change it to make it scroll down to see the other text )

Comment: @A Haworth I hope you would reply to the comment above @mplungjan hope you to you would have an answer thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).